# StringIndexOutOfBoundsException error for String.charAt

Tags: java, eclipse, jsoup, httpconnection

I've created a java application about getting element from a web page and this is the code.

```
public class rpms {

    public rpms() {

    }

    private static final String USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0";
    private static final String URL ="https://url.com";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        URLget labaccess = new URLget();

        try {
            getElementTd(sendGetRequest(URL).toString());
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static String sendGetRequest(String urlString) throws IOException {

        URL obj = new URL(urlString);
        HttpURLConnection httpConnection = (HttpURLConnection) obj
                .openConnection();

        httpConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");

        httpConnection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);

        int responseCode = httpConnection.getResponseCode();
        if (responseCode == 200) {

            BufferedReader responseReader = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(httpConnection.getInputStream()));

            String responseLine;
            StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

            while ((responseLine = responseReader.readLine()) != null) {
                response.append(responseLine + "\n");
            }
            responseReader.close();

            // print result
            return response.toString();
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static void getElementTd(String sourceCode)
            throws FileNotFoundException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
        String fragment = sourceCode;
        ArrayList<String> ip = new ArrayList<String>();
        Document doc = Jsoup.parseBodyFragment(fragment);

        Elements elements = doc.select("td p");

        for (int i = 0; i < elements.size(); i++) {
            // System.out.println(i+1+" ) "+elements.eq(i).text().toString());

            if (fileExplode(elements.eq(i).text().toString())) {
                System.out.println(elements.eq(i).text().toString());

            }
        }
    }

    public static boolean fileExplode(String str1) {
        boolean hasRPM = false;
        String[] split1 = str1.replace(".", " ").split(" ");

        for (int i = 0; i < split1.length; i++) {
            if ((i + 1) == split1.length) {
                if (split1[i].equalsIgnoreCase("rpm")
                        || (split1[i].charAt(0) == 'r'
                                && split1[i].charAt(1) == 'p' && split1[i]
                                .charAt(2) == 'm')) {
                    hasRPM = true;

                }break;
            }

        }
        return hasRPM;
    }   
}
```

But when I execute the code above. The error occur : Exception in thread "main" I don't know what does it mean. The charAt is on error.

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 0
 at java.lang.String.charAt(Unknown Source)
 at rpms.fileExplode(rpms.java:98)
 at rpms.getElementTd(rpms.java:82)
 at rpms.main(rpms.java:32)
```

To be more guided this is the number where the error occurs.

```
/*97*/ if (split1[split1.length - 1].equalsIgnoreCase("rpm")
/*98*/|| (split1[i].charAt(0) == 'r'
/*99*/ && split1[i].charAt(1) == 'p' && split1[i]
/*100*/ .charAt(2) == 'm')) {
```

```
/*82*/ if (fileExplode(elements.eq(i).text().toString())) {
/*83*/ System.out.println(elements.eq(i).text().toString());
/*84*/ }
```

```
/*32*/ getElementTd(sendGetRequest(URL).toString());
```

Please help me to solve the error occurred.

Comment: You're trying to get the first character of a string that is zero characters long.

Answer (score 1):

The error means that you tried to get a character from a string at an index that was greater than or equal to the length of the string. Specifically, it's when you tried to get the first character in `split[i]` on line 98. You never check if the size of `split1[i]` is greater than 0. I would suggest adding that.

```
for (int i = 0; i < split1.length; i++) {
    if ((i + 1) == split1.length) {
        if (split1[i].equalsIgnoreCase("rpm")
                || (split1[i].length > 2 && split1[i].charAt(0) == 'r'
                        && split1[i].charAt(1) == 'p' && split1[i]
                        .charAt(2) == 'm')) {
            hasRPM = true;
        }

        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: @chrisHayes Thank you for the answer, the error is now gone. it is solve

Comment: @blessJator It's actually doctordoder's answer, I just did a minor edit. If the answer helped you, make sure to accept it (click the checkbox next to the answer).

Comment: @ChrisHayes hahahha thanks Chris